# Email arrival (download) time in outlook add-in

Tags: .net, email, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

In an outlook 2007 add-in, MailItem.ReceivedTime contains the time at which an email arrived on the email server. Is the time at which the email is downloaded to outlook stored anywhere? If not, is the best way to store this to create my own custom property that I set myself in a handler for Application.NewMailEx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be PR_CREATION_TIME (or CreationTime), which is the time the item was created in the relevant data store in Outlook.